# Android - notifydatasetchanged does not work viewpager

Tags: java, android

UPDATED POST:

FriendsFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        parentView      = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friends, container, false);
        recyclerView    = (RecyclerView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.list_main);
        mArrayList  = new ArrayList<>();

        bindViews();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return parentView;
    }



private void bindViews() {
        parentActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        adapter = new PostThreadAdapter(parentView.getContext(),         postsArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(parentActivity);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
getItemsFromDatabase();
}

private getItemsFromDatabase()
{

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(StringRequest.Method.PUT, "SERVERURL", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    final FeedResponse feedResponse = gson.fromJson(response, FeedResponse.class);

  mArrayList.clear();
                        mArrayList.addAll(feedResponse.getArrayList());
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
  } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("C", "CATH " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
};

    volley.addRequest(stringRequest, "FriendsFragment");

}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            Collections.sort(mArrayList, new Comparator<Objectx>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Objectx d, Objectx t1) {
                        return t1.getPostType() - d.getPostType();
                    }
                });
         adapter.notifydatasetchanged(); // this only work the first time
   }
```

PROBLEM: 
I have 1 Activity (MainActivity)

My activity have framelayout and this can contain 2 fragments.

HomeFragment OR UserFragment

My HomeFragment have TabLayout and viewpager that contain 2 fragments:

Tab1: FriendsFragment
Tab2: NotifiFragment

In my friendsfragment I have recyclerview with custom adapter and viewholder. 
This works fine the first time, but when I change of fragment (from HomeFragment to UserFragment) and back again to Homefragment the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); don't work anymore. I already tried this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    array.clear();
    getInfoFromDatabase(); // this include .addAll array
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG, "List Frag Resumed");

}
```

Also:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(mView.getContext(), array);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
        getInfoFromDatabase(); // this include .addAll array
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d(TAG, "List Frag Resumed");

    }
```

But none works. I'm also using collections sort to order my items and I notice that the items of the array get changed but can't see in the app because notifydatasetchanged does nothing.

Comment: is `onresume`actually called?

Comment: Yes, I can see the log.

Comment: any crash or just notifydatasetchanged is not wokring

Comment: Nop, I don't have any crash. Is just that, is like don't reload the items. As I said, my array items get changed or oder but notifydatasetchanged does nothing

Comment: Well if you're going to create a new adapter every time onResume is called (bad practice by the way)then just populate the array with new data before you instantiate a new CustomAdapter and then just use setAdapter. Or post your adapter code and method to add new data, obviously the data in your Adapter and updated array aren't pointing to the same Object otherwise notifyDataSetChanged would work.

Comment: Please post what `getInfoFromDatabase()` looks like.

Comment: I don't want to do bad practice. I posted my code above, getInfoFromDatabase is a volley request to get data from my server

Comment: A Volley request is asynchronous, so you will need to call the notify in the callback.

Comment: Yes But I think that isn't the error because the first time works fine. The error is when I change of fragment then back to FriendsFragment and I tried to sort the items. The array get changed as should be but the list doesn't change

Comment: Can be something of the cache of viewpager? Because As I said HomeFragment have 2 childs.